# Mixed Effects: How to Account for (Complicated) Interdependency Nested within Trials?

Tags: mixed-model, model, lme4-nlme, effects

This is an issue I've been discussing in-depth with with my stats tutor without being able to figure it out. I am very, very grateful for any useful insight.

**Core Question:**
In each trial, participants in my experiment allocate a total of 100 points (let's call it a bonus) between four investment bankers. How can we create a mixed effects model which accounts for the interdependency between the bonus nested within each trial?

**Experimental Design:**
In my experiment for my master's thesis I am looking into a phenomenon known as [outcome bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outcome_bias). Participants act as managers for a team of four investment bankers over the course of 12 trials.

In the trials in the control condition, participants first observe some decisions being made by the four bankers. Then the outcomes of both the chosen and foregone alternative are displayed to the participants and they are asked to allocate 100 points between the bankers based on the decision quality displayed by the bankers. What we’re interested in is whether the points (a continuous variable) actually are allocated based on the quality of the decision (a binary variable, correct / incorrect based on expected values) or the outcome of the banker’s decision (continuous variable).

A second condition includes an intervention which we believe might shift the emphasis from the outcome to the actual decision. The only thing that is different in this condition is that participants are asked to make a preliminary allocation of the decision-points just after the decisions are revealed but before the outcomes of the decisions are known. After the outcomes are revealed, participants are allowed to make adjustments to the final allocation.

Below you can see an illustration of the design. The alternatives with red backgrounds are those chosen by the bankers. Please note that the $100,000 bonus has been updated to 100 decision points in the actual experience, not that it matters in this domain.

[image: Illustration of experimental design]

**The Issue:**
Our goal is to compare compare the effect outcome has on the allocation of decision-points between the two conditions. For this we are planning to do a mixed effects model which accounts for the interdepence both between subjects (as they do multiple trials) and between bankers (as the allocation occurs in sets of four and that the is an upper limit of 100 points in each trial).

One idea was to run the following:

```
model <- lmer(bonus ~ outcome + decision + condition + outcome*condition + 
(1 | subject) + (1 | trial/banker), data = xxx)
```

Where the last part specifies that bankers are nested within trials, however this will not be sufficient as a random intercept for each trial would still not make it clear in the model that the bankers come in sets of four.

Is there any way to account for this dependency?

**End Note:**
Yes, I know I probably should have mapped out these issues before kicking off the experiment, but this is the first time I am doing this and I guess running into problems like this is the best way to learn, right?